# How To Get image <input> from HTML in flask

Tags: html, python-3.x, forms, flask, webserver

Quick question as I can't really find this anywhere else.

If I had an input that is formed like this:

```
<input type="image" name="Text" value="text" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/icons/General/Post.svg') }}" />
```

How Can I retrieve this being pressed with `request.form[]`?

I get an KeyError with the following:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    if request.form["Text"] == "text":
        return render_template("PostText.html")
```

I know there is a similar way of retrieving data using `<input type="submit" value="text">` but it doesn't work with the former.

Thanks!

Edit: fixed formatting and grammar.

TLDR: I can't detect an input with the type of `image` from flask in python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image):

> for input elements of type image the value attribute should not be
>   specified

The value will always be *None*

Comment: request.form["Text"] == None? I'm assuming you have another button and you are trying to differentiate between the two submits?